# Thymeleaf input type="date" can not display and update

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I can't find the right way to display the "birthday" field from datbase!
Even when i try to submit the new value to db, it doesn't work. What i'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/settings"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView settings() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

         model.addObject("user", user);
         model.addObject("countries", getListOfCountries());
         model.setViewName("user/settings");

        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/settings"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView updateUserGeneralSettings(@ModelAttribute User user) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        userService.update(user);

        model.addObject("user", user);
        model.addObject("countries", getListOfCountries());


        model.setViewName("user/settings");
        return model;
    }
```

HTML

```
   <form method="POST" th:action="@{/settings}" th:object="${user}">
    <div>
    </div>
    ...
    ...

    <div class="costum-field">
        <label for="dateOfBirth" th:text="#{field.dateOfBirth}"></label>
        <input type="date" id="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" th:field="*{dateOfBirth}"/>
    </div>
    ...
    ...
    <div>
    </div>
    </form
```

View in browser
[image]

So, as you can see all fields are working properly. Please suggest what is my mistake.

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = {"/settings"},method)` -> the same mapping for both GET & POST???

Comment: are you using bootstrap? refer here: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: @N00b Pr0grammer , Yes, i'm using the same mapping, it can work like this because submitting form will choose the POST method.

Comment: @dsharew, no. At the moment i want just to read data from User object and display it.